# React-Native scrollToEnd on iOS behaves differently than scrolling manually, putting items to bottom

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview

Please consider this example on iOS: https://sketch.expo.io/SyeyMSx_il

- Try to scroll **manually**, everything looks normal: *No comments* message stays on top.
- If you **click now on the button now**, the *No comments* message sticks to the bottom.
- If you scroll **manually** again, everything goes normal again.

Why using scrollToEnd should be different than scrolling manually? And how to fix this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to ScrollView `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` fixed that.
See now: https://snack.expo.io/HkdP9_e1Z

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the cause of the behaviour without digging through the source code for ScrollView but you could get around it by making a function that handles the scroll to end, only triggering it if the size of the contents are greater than the size of the viewport.